# Can't call a function from Spark Streaming 'RDD.foreachPartition' but copying all lines of the function works

Tags: apache-spark, apache-kafka, spark-streaming

I am trying to create a stream a Spark RDD from a Worker node instead of collecting it at the Driver first. So I created the following code

```
  def writeToKafka[K: ClassTag, V: ClassTag](rdd: RDD[(K, V)], topic: String, keySerializerClass: String, valueSerializerClass: String, brokers: String = producerBroker) = {
    rdd.foreachPartition { partitionOfRecords =>
      val producer = new KafkaProducer[K, V](getProducerProps(keySerializerClass, valueSerializerClass, brokers))
      partitionOfRecords.foreach { message =>
        producer.send(new ProducerRecord[K, V](topic, message._1, message._2))
      }
      producer.close()
    }
  }

  def getProducerProps(keySerializerClass: String, valueSerializerClass: String, brokers: String): Properties = {
    val producerProps: Properties = new Properties
    producerProps.put(ProducerConfig.BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG, brokers)
    producerProps.put(ProducerConfig.KEY_SERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, keySerializerClass)
    producerProps.put(ProducerConfig.VALUE_SERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, valueSerializerClass)
    producerProps
  }
```

Running this code causes the following exception

```
15/09/01 15:13:00 ERROR JobScheduler: Error running job streaming job 1441120380000 ms.3
org.apache.spark.SparkException: Task not serializable
at org.apache.spark.util.ClosureCleaner$.ensureSerializable(ClosureCleaner.scala:166)
at org.apache.spark.util.ClosureCleaner$.clean(ClosureCleaner.scala:158)
at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.clean(SparkContext.scala:1623)
at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.foreachPartition(RDD.scala:805)
at com.company.opt.detector.StreamingDetector.writeToKafka(StreamingDetector.scala:84)
at com.company.opt.MyClass.MyClass$$anonfun$doStreamingWork$3.apply(MyClass.scala:47)
at com.company.opt.MyClass.MyClass$$anonfun$doStreamingWork$3.apply(MyClass.scala:47)
at org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.DStream$$anonfun$foreachRDD$1.apply(DStream.scala:534)
at org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.DStream$$anonfun$foreachRDD$1.apply(DStream.scala:534)
at org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.ForEachDStream$$anonfun$1.apply$mcV$sp(ForEachDStream.scala:42)
at org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.ForEachDStream$$anonfun$1.apply(ForEachDStream.scala:40)
at org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.ForEachDStream$$anonfun$1.apply(ForEachDStream.scala:40)
at scala.util.Try$.apply(Try.scala:161)
at org.apache.spark.streaming.scheduler.Job.run(Job.scala:32)
at org.apache.spark.streaming.scheduler.JobScheduler$JobHandler$$anonfun$run$1.apply$mcV$sp(JobScheduler.scala:176)
at org.apache.spark.streaming.scheduler.JobScheduler$JobHandler$$anonfun$run$1.apply(JobScheduler.scala:176)
at org.apache.spark.streaming.scheduler.JobScheduler$JobHandler$$anonfun$run$1.apply(JobScheduler.scala:176)
at scala.util.DynamicVariable.withValue(DynamicVariable.scala:57)
at org.apache.spark.streaming.scheduler.JobScheduler$JobHandler.run(JobScheduler.scala:175)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.io.NotSerializableException: com.company.opt.MyClass.MyClass$
Serialization stack:
- object not serializable (class: com.company.opt.MyClass.MyClass$, value: com.company.opt.MyClass.MyClass$@7e2bb5e0)
- field (class: com.company.opt.detector.StreamingDetector$$anonfun$writeToKafka$1, name: $outer, type: class com.company.opt.detector.StreamingDetector)
- object (class com.company.opt.detector.StreamingDetector$$anonfun$writeToKafka$1, <function1>)
at org.apache.spark.serializer.SerializationDebugger$.improveException(SerializationDebugger.scala:38)
at org.apache.spark.serializer.JavaSerializationStream.writeObject(JavaSerializer.scala:47)
at org.apache.spark.serializer.JavaSerializerInstance.serialize(JavaSerializer.scala:80)
at org.apache.spark.util.ClosureCleaner$.ensureSerializable(ClosureCleaner.scala:164)
... 21 more
```

However when I just copy the code from the `getProducerProps` function directly into my `writeToKafka` function, as follows, everything works correctly.

```
  def writeToKafka[K: ClassTag, V: ClassTag](rdd: RDD[(K, V)], topic: String, keySerializerClass: String, valueSerializerClass: String, brokers: String = producerBroker) = {
    rdd.foreachPartition { partitionOfRecords =>
      val producerProps: Properties = new Properties
      producerProps.put(ProducerConfig.BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG, brokers)
      producerProps.put(ProducerConfig.KEY_SERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, keySerializerClass)
      producerProps.put(ProducerConfig.VALUE_SERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, valueSerializerClass)
      val producer = new KafkaProducer[K, V](producerProps)
      partitionOfRecords.foreach { message =>
        producer.send(new ProducerRecord[K, V](topic, message._1, message._2))
      }
      producer.close()
    }
  }
```

Can someone explain why this happens? Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Given that `getProducerProps` is a method of the class enclosing it, when it's used from the closure, it's equivalent to do `this.getProducerProps(...)`. 
Then the issue becomes evident: `this` is being pulled into the closure and needs to be serialized, together with all other fields. Some member of that class is not serializable and gives this exception.

A good practice is to put such methods is a separate object:

```
object ProducerUtils extends Serializable {
 def getProducerProps(keySerializerClass: String, valueSerializerClass: String, brokers: String): Properties = ???
}
```

Another way is to make that method a function and assign it to a `val`. Then, the value of that `val` is inlined an therefore will not pull the whole instance into the serializable closure:

```
val producerProps: (String,String,String) => Properties = ???
```

Comment: That makes sense now. I spent quite some time pulling my hair over this one. Thanks for the explanation.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with maasg's answer, maybe you would found interesting [this post](http://erikerlandson.github.io/blog/2015/03/31/hygienic-closures-for-scala-function-serialization/) exploring the topic of ensuring which data in a closure is serialized by Spark